# vscode-setting. Can not validate php.Using LAMP

Tags: php, lamp, visual-studio-code

It can not be validated since in PHP the executable has been established. I am using LAMP from Bitnami.

I'm in the fedora distribution 25. I've tried the following:

`"php.validate.executablePath": "/home/myname/lampstack-7.1.4-0/php/bin",`

Thanks.

Comment: Try `$ which php` perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to point it to `php` directly, not just `php`'s path, so I guess you'll have to set it like this:

`"php.validate.executablePath": "/home/myname/lampstack-7.1.4-0/php/bin/php"`